# How to concatenate cells in dataframe column into lists if they have same corresponding values in another column??[Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm only a beginner so please excuse any mistakes. I would really appreciate some guidance as I am really stuck.

I have a df as follows:

```
client                         referer                                               
1.158.74.178  xyz.com/m/product/30499  
1.158.74.178  xyz.com/m/product/30516  
1.36.128.224  xyz.com/browse/etching  
1.36.128.224  xyz.com/browse/handy-crafts  
1.43.175.52   xyz.com/browse/chairs
.
.
.
```

**WHAT I NEED**

I want to get the URLs which belong to the same client in a single column and separated by commas
i.e. something like this:

```
1.158.74.178  xyz.com/m/product/30499,xyz.com/m/product/30516
1.36.128.224  xyz.com/browse/etching,xyz.com/browse/handy-crafts
1.43.175.52   xyz.com/browse/chairs
```

...and so on.

Ultimately, I would like to convert each 'cell' in the 'referer' column into a list and append each list into a list of lists and get a dataset as follows:

```
[['xyz.com/m/product/30499','xyz.com/m/product/30516'],['xyz.com/browse/etching','xyz.com/browse/handy-crafts'],['xyz.com/browse/chairs'],...]
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I created the original dataframe from a Series using

```
d5 = d4.to_frame().reset_index().set_index('client')
d5.rename(columns = {0:'client', 1:'referer'}, inplace=True)
d5 = d5.loc[:, ['client','referer']]
```

thereby assigning 'client' as index. When I tried it without setting the index, it skewed the dataframe considerably. So changing the index is not an option I guess.

**So when I tried-**

```
df = d5.groupby(d5.iloc[:,0])['referer'].apply(','.join)
```

or

```
df = d5.groupby(d5.loc[d5.loc[:,'client']])['referer'].apply(','.join)
```

it gives me the error-

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
d = {'referer':','.join}
d6 = d5.groupby('client').agg(d).reset_index()
```

gives me the error-

ValueError: 'client' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

I already checked a bunch of answers but I keep getting errors.

I'm all out of ideas. Help??

Comment: you should have a column as either an index or a column, drop the index and group on column: `df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby('client').agg(', '.join)` ?

Comment: If you found a solution then add it where it belongs in an answer. Solutions can't be part of the question

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
df = df.groupby('client').agg(', '.join)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                                                        referer
client                                                         
1.158.74.178   xyz.com/m/product/30499, xyz.com/m/product/30516
1.36.128.224  xyz.com/browse/etching, xyz.com/browse/handy-c...
1.43.175.52                               xyz.com/browse/chairs
```

2nd part:

```
# required_list = df.groupby('client').agg(list).values
required_list = df.groupby('client').agg(list)['referer'].to_list()
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['xyz.com/m/product/30499', 'xyz.com/m/product/30516'],
 ['xyz.com/browse/etching', 'xyz.com/browse/handy-crafts'],
 ['xyz.com/browse/chairs']]
```

Comment: `df = df.groupby('client').agg(', '.join)` gives the same error:
ValueError: 'client' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous. Any idea how I can modify the code to fix this?? 
If I change the groupby argument using loc or iloc it gives me the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error

Comment: what's the name of your index column? In the dataframe above there are only `2 columns`.

Comment: I've set 'client' as index. If I omit set_index('client') when I convert the Series to df thats shown above, it adds a weird filler column in between so I'm trying to work around keeping the client column as index while grouping with it; If that's possible?

Comment: Can you add your initial dataframe in yours post?